# Como adicionar item para uma lista de array no angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho uma tela de cadastro de roteiro e nessa tela posso adicionar n cenários, estou usando angular, eu consigo adicionar os itens na lista, mas enquanto vou digitando no input ele vai alterando os itens que já está adicionado a lista.

commponent.ts

```
incluirCenario() {

    this.cenario.push(
      {}
    )

}
```

html

```
<mat-card-title>Cadastrar Cenário</mat-card-title>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width:40%">
       <mat-label>Nome do Cenário:</mat-label>
       <input matInput type="text" formControlName="nomeCenario" [(ngModel)]="cenario.nome" maxlength="100" />
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-button (click)="incluirCenario()" color="primary" >Incluir
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara, poderia postar a parte do código da lista na pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Débora, não consegui compreender o seu código porquê tem uma rotina `this.cenario.push()` e um objeto `cenario` no ngModel. Eu imagino que o primeiro seria um array de cenários e o segundo um objeto em edição, vou então renomeálos para simular seu ambiente.

É provável que você vá conseguir solucionar seu problema usando o operador spread (`...`). O que ele faz é clonar o objeto sem manter a referência. O que isto quer dizer? Um objeto referenciado é apenas 1 único objeto e os demais são variáveis apontadas (ponteiros) para ele, quando este objeto é alterado, as variáveis vão refletir as alterações deste objeto.

Você deveria então criar uma cópia deste objeto ao adicionar no array, desta seguinte forma:

```
listaCenario: CenarioObj[] = [];
cenario: CenarioObj;

incluirCenario() {
    this.cenario.push({...this.cenario});
}
```

Assim cada push que você dá na lista uma nova cópia do objeto é inserida em vez de apenas um "apontamento" para o objeto principal.

Lembrando: Assim mantém referência `.push(objeto);` e assim não  `.push({...objeto});`.

Comment: Desculpe a falta de clareza, estou iniciando. Muito obrigada pela explicação. Fiz o que disse e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Exatamente isso que não estava enxergando!

Declarei uma lista de cenários:

```
protected cenarios: Cenario[] = []
  protected cenario: Cenario = new Cenario();
```

No método de inclusão fiz referência do this.cenario.nome para o this.roteiroAddForm.nomeCenario do formGroup.

```
 incluirCenario() {

    this.cenario.nome = this.roteiroAddForm.nomeCenario;
    this.cenarios.push({...this.cenario});


  }
```

Utilizando o spread para remover a referencia do objeto, assim consigo inserir novos registos a lista sem alterar os registros que já estavam adicionados.

sem a necessidade de usar o ngModel o meu código html ficou assim:

```
<mat-card>
          <mat-card-title>Cadastrar Cenário</mat-card-title>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width:40%">
            <mat-label>Nome do Cenário:</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="nomeCenario"  maxlength="100" />
          </mat-form-field>
          <button mat-button (click)="incluirCenario(cenario)" color="primary" >Incluir
            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-card>
```

Comment: Bacana, para um iniciante o código tá muito bom. Continue nesta pegada.